# For loops with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to use a for loop to identify a quadrant that a point (defined by a tuple) is in.

The program prompts until a non-numerical answer is given. Then, using the points input by the user, I need to identify which quadrant each point would be in.

For example: points (0, 1),(1,2),(2,3), and (3,4) are stored in a list and need their quadrants identified by a for loop.

I am unsure where to start with this. My input code is as follows:

```
locationlist = []
count = 0

while True :
    try : 
        tup = input("Enter X and Y separated by a space, or enter a non-number to stop: ")
        x, y = tup.split()
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        count = count + 1
        locationlist.append(tup)
    except ValueError:
        break
print("Points: ",locationlist)
```

Comment: Do you want to verify if square that is created by points provided by user is a proper square? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Given a point, how would you "identify the quadrant" by hand? It's not entirely clear what your expected output is

Comment: @blazej the goal is to have each point the user input be labeled as Quadrant 1, Quadrant 2, etc depending on where the quadrant is, using a for loop

Comment: @G.Anderson I need to use a for loop to analyze the x and y values of each input to determine what quadrant the point would be in. But I do not know what parameters I should put for the "for" statement

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that's how you described in the question. My follow up is to ask you, if you were doing it on, say, a piece of paper, what process or algorithm would you do do determine what quadrant a point would be in? If you can describe the process in plain words, that can help you to translate it into code, and help us to understand how to help you

Comment: @blazej thats ok. Im a beginner so my wording isnt very technical.

Comment: @G.Anderson I see, in that case I would like look at the first, second, third, etc. values in "locationlist" and from each entry to the list determine which quadrant.

Comment: _"But I do not know what parameters I should put for the "for" statement"_: What do you want to iterate over? Have you finished your tutorial on for loops? The general format of a for loop is `for item in collection: do something with item`

Comment: @G.Anderson I think i figured it out, thanks to you and some of the other responders. Thank you

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've figured it out now, and I have, I just struggle to identify sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create extra variables for that, just nest your test.

```
for x, y in locationList:
    if y >= 0:
        if x >= 0:  print( x, y, 'Quadrant 1' )
        else:     print( x, y, 'Quadrant 2' )
    else:  ##  y < 0
        if x < 0:  print( x, y, 'Quadrant 3' )
        else:     print( x, y, 'Quadrant 4' )
```

---

**Edit:** If axis is required:

```
for x, y in locationList:
    if y > 0:
        if x > 0:  print( x, y, 'Quadrant 1' )
        elif x < 0: print( x, y, 'Quadrant 2' )
        else:      print( x, y, 'pos Y-axis' )

    elif y < 0
        if x < 0:  print( x, y, 'Quadrant 3' )
        elif x > 0: print( x, y, 'Quadrant 4' )
        else:      print( x, y, 'neg Y-axis' )

    else:
        if x > 0:  print( x, y, 'pos X-axis' )
        elif x < 0: print( x, y, 'neg X-axis' )
        else:  print( x, y, 'Origin' )
```

Comment: For this solution, I would be concerned about what happens on the axes. You should decide what you want to have happen on the axes, and code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are asking for:

```
for x, y in locationList:
    a = x > 0
    b = y > 0
    c = x == 0 or y == 0
    
    if not c:
        if a and b:
            # 1st quadrant
        elif a:
            # 4th quadrant
        elif b:
            # 2nd quadrant
        else:
            # 3rd quadrant
    else:
        # no quadrant
```

Basically what I'm doing is storing the conditions of whether x and y are positive or not, so that I can do logic on those without repeatedly calculating those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use a divide-and-conquer strategy to reduce the number of comparisons. Perhaps something like this:

```
for x, y in locationList:

    # 2nd or 4th
    if x * y < 0:
        if x < 0:
            # Second quadrant.
        else:
            # Fourth quadrant.

    # 1st or 3rd
    elif x * y > 0:
        if x < 0:
            # Third quadrant.
        else:
            # First quadrant.

    # On an axis: quadrant not well-defined.
    else:
        # No quadrant.
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense